# How to blocksites in hosts file?

Tags: web, block, hosts

I want to block all websites which url contains 'games' keyword.

I know, this is the single method:

```
127.0.0.1   http://games.com/
```

But, how can i block all 'games' websites?

I tried this, but not working:

```
127.0.0.1 http://*games*
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wildcard matching isn't supported in `/etc/hosts` on Windows or Linux.

If you want to use wildcard matching for 'games', you'll have to download a local DNS proxy that has this feature.